# Pass string macro into C program - cross-platform

Tags: c, linux, windows, macros

I need to pass a string value into my C program at compile time:

```
-DNAME=value
```

I know of two ways to do this:  Stringification as described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
...
printf("%s\n", xstr(NAME));
```

The problem I have here is that macros inside the string are substituted, so as my string contains `-linux-` it becomes `-1-` on linux.

The other way is to try to quote the string correctly when passing.  I'm doing this from a Python `setup.py` file as follows:

```
macros = [('NAME', '"value"')]
```

or equivalently

```
-DNAME='"value"'
```

Then I just

```
printf("%s\n", NAME);
```

But I can't find a way to do this correctly both on Linux (gcc) and Windows (MSVC 9 for Python 2.7).

This may be complicated by the fact that the string may contain `/`, `\` or `%` and so I need to do some escaping.

---

Let's bring this back to `setup.py`, which is where this needs to work.

```
value = '"value"'   # works on Linux but not Windows
value = '\\"value\\"'   # works on Windows but not Linux
```

Comment: Why not simply *define* the macro as a string? Like `-DNAME="value"` (note the double quotes).

Comment: That's the second way above.  I have to do `-DNAME='"value"'`.  But it doesn't seem to work on Windows.

Comment: Drop the single quotes, keep the double quotes.

Comment: That doesn't even compile.  The quotes don't get passed through by the shell.

Comment: Ah of course, in a shell you need to escape them: `-DNAME=\"value\"`. Still no single quotes, but backslashes and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm in Python, I can handle the platform specifics manually:

```
value = 'my/complicated%/string'
quoted_value = '"{}"'.format(value)
if sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    quoted_value = quoted_value.replace('%', '%%')
    quoted_value = quoted_value.replace('"', '\\"')
```

Further special characters would complicate this further.